# Moodle Help on Quiz Questions Numbering : Multiple Questions within single Embedded Answers (Cloze) type

Tags: moodle

I created, in a quiz, an embedded answers ( cloze ) type question. Within it, I created a paragraph with fill up the blanks : using codes for "shortanswer".

My issue and question is : There are 4 fill up the blanks. The question number that i typed in this paragraph is 6. Each of the blanks, has to be a question in the quiz ie 4 blanks : have to get counted as question numbers 6,7,8,9.

The next question is to be numbered 10. But it is 7.

I realize that i have created only 1 question, so next is 7. And that embedded answers type is about multiple answers not questions.

I have checked the syntax for embedded answers.

Is there any way, that i can have multiple questions so that the next question is number 10 ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you have line breaks inside your Cloze question as described [here](https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Embedded_Answers_(Cloze)_question_type) it will recognize 4 questions, not one question with 4 answers. The Cloze question should be set to have a default score out of 4, with each answer weighted appropriately.

If this doesn't fix it edit your question to include the whole Cloze question code.